# Generating Pivot for the last updated row

Tags: vba, excel

I have two sheets. Sheet1 "Result" which has an table that contains 8 columns.

I have the second sheet "Sum" where I am generating an Pivot table for the Reuslt sheet.

The code, works fine, but it calculates the sum of each and every column and gives the result.

I would like to have the pivot table only for the last updated row.

Each and everyweek the last update row changes. Next week ,the updates will be found in 17th and so on...

[image: I have an sheet with table as shown and the pivot tables are generated in another sheet(Example shows an sample), with the below code, I get the sum of the complete column. But I would like to have the result of only the last update as shows in table2 of my figure]

Could anyone suggest how I could do it? any lead would be helpful

```
Sub sum2017()
Dim ws9 As Worksheet
Dim pc9 As PivotCache
Dim pt9 As PivotTable
Dim ct9 As Integer
Set ws9 = Sheets("Sum")
Set pc9 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'Result'!R1C1:R1048576C6")
Set pt9 = pc9.CreatePivotTable(ws9.Range("A3"))
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("NOK"), "Sum of NOK", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("OK"), "Sum of OK", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("Total"), "Sum of Total", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("NOK %"), "Sum of NOK %", xlSum
pt9.AddDataField pt9.PivotFields("OK %"), "Sum of OK %", xlSum
pt9.DataLabelRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
pt9.DataLabelRange.ReadingOrder = xlContext
pt9.TableRange2.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End Sub
```

[image: This is how my source data looks like. and I would like to have the Last filled row. this week number is 30, so row 30 is filled.next week will be 31, and I want the pivot table to take only the values of 31.]

Comment: paste this code in the change event of the cell in that sheet.

Comment: Create the `PivotCache` SoureData only from the last row of your data

Comment: which code ? @nishitdey

Comment: @ShaiRado but wont that be a temporary solution. next week,the row will change ..

Comment: The above code you have written, that will do the trick

Comment: @Jenny No, cause you can get the last row in a dynamic way

Comment: @ShaiRado How do I do that ? in a dynamic way ?

Comment: Get the last row in column "A" in "Result" worksheet : `LastRow = Worksheets("Result").Cells(Worksheets("Result").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @ShaiRado I think, I need to be clear. I have the column A with weeknumber from 1 to 50, ryt now the week 30 is filled, so the upper rows have data in alternative week and the below week 30, the data are not present. So defining the last row, will look for empty rows right ? but my data is in row 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, but every time will add help sheet when new pivottable is created. If you dont want to do that, just add some extra sheet, name it as you want to, than change referece of wskHelpSheet to that sheet and remember to always clean this worksheet at the start of your macro. I hope that it sound clear to you :)

```
    Sub sum2017()

Dim ws9 As Worksheet
Dim wskResult As Worksheet
Dim pc9 As PivotCache
Dim pt9 As PivotTable
Dim ct9 As Integer
Dim rngPivotRangeHeaders As Range
Dim lngLRow As Long
Dim lngLCol As Long
Dim rngPivotRangeRecords As Range
Dim rngPTRange As Range
Dim wskHelpSheet As Worksheet

    Set ws9 = Sheets("Sum")
    Set wskResult = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")
    Set wskHelpSheet = Worksheets.Add
    With wskResult
        lngLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        lngLCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rngPivotRangeHeaders = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lngLCol))
        Set rngPivotRangeRecords = .Range(.Cells(lngLRow, 1), .Cells(lngLRow, lngLCol))
        Set rngPTRange = Union(rngPivotRangeHeaders, rngPivotRangeRecords)
        rngPTRange.Copy
    End With

    With wskHelpSheet
        .Range("a1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        lngLRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        lngLCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set rngPTRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLRow, lngLCol))
    End With

    Set pc9 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, rngPTRange)
    Set pt9 = pc9.CreatePivotTable(ws9.Range("A3"))

    With pt9
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("NOK"), "Sum of NOK", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("OK"), "Sum of OK", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("Total"), "Sum of Total", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("NOK %"), "Sum of NOK %", xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields("OK %"), "Sum of OK %", xlSum
        .DataLabelRange.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .DataLabelRange.ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .TableRange2.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @maajo , I am getting application defined error in the line Set pt9 = pc9.CreatePivotTable(ws9.Range("A3"))

Comment: @maajo, In between the rows I have some blank rows as well. does it affect in anyway?

Comment: Hi Jenny, no it doesn't affect it, i Know where is the problem, give me 3 minutes and i will try to solve it

Comment: sure. I will hold till then

Comment: just on looking my image, I noticed that the rows empty below are not visible. I would like to add an point.may be it is need to be considered. I have the column A in result sheet which denotes the weeknumber. The weeknumber starts from 1 and end till 52. Ryt now we are in week30, so the week30 is filled, and the below rows from 31 till 52 are still empty.

Comment: I just edited my previous code, take a look and also please read the header.

Comment: @maajo I just realised and added the main pint in my comment.and I could notice that the code takes the last row. I need the "Last updated row" which is row 30 in my case. the rest of the rows below ranging from 31 to 52 are empty. Could you please consider this point and help me?

Comment: Can you paste here a screenshot how the source data for PivotTable is looking? Because the printscren in first sheet is showing only some piece of data

Comment: Ya, I iwill post the data now.

Comment: Jenny, please try the code now. I made one small adjustment, it should help you

Comment: @maajo I have added the source table how it looks

Comment: I tried, It works great :)  thank you for your support :)